# Progress bar to prevent 504 Gateway TimeOut in ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE

Tags: php

I'm creating a zip with php with big files like videos. The ZIP should be around 500mb and the php crash with 504 Gateway TimeOut when i try to makeit. I want to add a progress bar or something to avoid the server saturation, i think the key is in the foreach when add files.

```
foreach($post['files'] as $file) { 
$zip->addFile($file,basename($file));
}
```

i already setup max_execution_time

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Any idea how is the best way?

Complete code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);


if(isset($_POST['files']))
{ $error = ""; //error holder
{

$post = $_POST; 
$file_folder = "files/"; // folder to load files
if(extension_loaded('zip'))
{ 
// Checking ZIP extension is available
if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
{ 
// Checking files are selected

$casting_titulo = $post['casting_titulo'];

$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = $titulo."cast.zip"; // Zip name
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)


{ 

 // Opening zip file to load files
$error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

foreach($post['files'] as $file) { 
$zip->addFile($file,basename($file));
}


$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name))
{
// push to download the zip
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
readfile($zip_name);
// remove zip file is exists in temp path
unlink($zip_name);
}}
else $error .= "* Please select file to zip "; }
else $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension"; }
}

?>
```

Comment: We need to know more about your environment. If your max_execution_time is already set to 0 the timeout is either occurring as part of your web server or an intermediate load balancer. What web server are you running (e.g. Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc)? Are you running the application through any load balancers or reverse proxies?

Comment: I don't have the access to the server to change Nginx configuration, so the best i think is force to a lower activity to not collapse the server, is not possible to add a progress bar or something like that?

Comment: how to solved this problem bro?